# how to cancel/stop then restart Thread in android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-listview, thread-safety

I have a thread. That thread loads data from the server and sets it in list view.

I want to **cancel** or **stop** the thread **then restart** this thread when a restart button is clicked.

I've used `while(true)` and use `interrupt` thread and use `stop()` but nothing works!

Answer (score 1):

You can't restart a Thread throws IllegalThreadStateException  , if the Thread has been started before/

For stopping or starting the thread use the below code

```
import android.util.Log;

public class ThreadingEx implements Runnable {

    private  Thread backgroundThread;
    private static final String TAG = ThreadingEx.class.getName();


    public void start() {
       if( backgroundThread == null ) {
          backgroundThread = new Thread( this );
          backgroundThread.start();
       }
    }

    public void stop() {
       if( backgroundThread != null ) {
          backgroundThread.interrupt();
       }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
           Log.i(TAG,"Starting.");
           while( !backgroundThread.interrupted() ) {
             //To Do
           }
           Log.i(TAG,"Stopping.");
        } catch( Exception ex ) {

           Log.i(TAG,"Exception."+ex);
        } finally {
           backgroundThread = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private Thread mThread;  

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);


    mThread =  new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        // Perform thread commands...
for (int i=0; i < 5000; i++)
{
  // do something...
}

// Call the stopThread() method.
        stopThread(this);
      }
    };

// Start the thread.
    mThread.start(); 
}

private synchronized void stopThread(Thread theThread)
{
if (theThread != null)
{
    theThread = null;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a field to tell your thread to stop, restart or cancel.

```
class TheThread extends Thread {
    private boolean running = true;

    public void run() {
        // do this...
        // do that...
        // .......

        if (!running) return;

        //Continue your job
    }
}
```